# My .py file I just converted into a .exe closes whenever I click enter to enter a input

Tags: python

**Here is my code: (link shortener)**

import pyshorteners

url = input("Enter the link you would like to shorten: ")

s = pyshorteners.Shortener()

s_link = s.tinyurl.short(url)

print("Here is your shortened link: " + s_link)

input()

Comment: Are you running your .exe from the command line?

Comment: Like @AbhyudayaSharma suggested, you should run from command line. Often times if there are errors when your EXE files run, they pop up in a command prompt window quickly and then disappear.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a problem when I run it. Try reinstalling pyshorteners or using a different link

Comment: it works just fine in vs code, but when I convert it into a .exe file with pyinstaller, it just closes after I input the link